# update manager fails

Tags: update-manager

I'm trying to update my Ubuntu system, but cannot do anything with the Update Manager. I get the following error message:

```
Could not initialize the package information
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems, 
E:The package perl-base needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @AFEEDSM did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: 12.04 ubuntu version

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should update the package lists, and the problem may have been caused a process being terminated while in the middle of updating. Make sure not to interrupt it this time.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will upgrade all packages, and hopefully there will be no errors. If this works, then chances are that when you open up Update Manager again, there won't be any errors.

To remove a broken repository, run the following in the terminal:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
ls
```

Extra repositories will be listed. To delete the one you don't want any more:

```
sudo rm <file>
```

For example:

```
sudo rm opera.list
```

Then, run the first two commands again (`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`). This time, there should be no errors.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://deb.opera.com/opera-beta/dists/stable/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to deb.opera.com:http:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: That's an old Opera repo that doesn't exist any more. The others should still work, however.

Comment: then how can i fix my problem ??????????

Comment: I will update my answer, hang on...

Comment: updated it. BTW do you still use Opera?

Comment: root@afeed-Vostro-1540:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# ls
ferramroberto-minitube-precise.list       google-talkplugin.list.save
ferramroberto-minitube-precise.list.save  upubuntu-com-xampp-precise.list
google-chrome.list                        upubuntu-com-xampp-precise.list.save
google-chrome.list.save                   videolan-stable-daily-precise.list
google-talkplugin.list

Comment: what's the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: root@afeed-Vostro-1540:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# sudo apt-get update
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg

Comment: thanks, what's the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep opera`?

Comment: root@afeed-Vostro-1540:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory

Comment: root@afeed-Vostro-1540:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep opera
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory

Comment: hang on a minute...

Comment: run `sudo wget 'http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt/sources_4e6610edce42a24a2a6a6fb20062756338120ffd.txt' -O /etc/apt/sources.list` and run the `cat` command again

Comment: sorry, ignore the last comment. Run `sudo wget 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tech4david/1d5bb9ff98e8cf05558a/raw/9c77c8c9da19e35a784ef2cd468b823f2338cd04/sources.list' -O /etc/apt/sources.list` and then run the `cat` command again.

Comment: root@afeed-Vostro-1540:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# sudo wget 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tech4david/1d5bb9ff98e8cf05558a/raw/9c77c8c9‌​da19e35a784ef2cd468b823f2338cd04/sources.list' -O /etc/apt/sources.list 
--2015-05-28 13:36:36--  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tech4david/1d5bb9ff98e8cf05558a

Comment: Connecting to gist.githubusercontent.com (gist.githubusercontent.com)|185.31.17.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-05-28 13:36:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2015-05-28 13:36:37--  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tech4david/1d5bb9ff98e8cf05558a/raw/9c77c8c9%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bda19e35a784ef2cd468b823f2338cd04/sources.list
Connecting to gist.githubusercontent.com (gist.githubusercontent.com)|185.31.17.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-05-28 13:36:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: see this -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Open a terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall perl-base
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

Explanation

- `apt-get update`

  - `update`

    update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources.
- `apt-get install --reinstall`

  - `install`

    install is followed by one or more packages desired for installation or upgrading.
  - `--reinstall`

    Re-install packages that are already installed and at the newest version.
- `apt-get upgrade`

  - `upgrade`

    upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: afeed@afeed-Vostro-1540:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall perl-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package perl-base needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: Please add information by editing your original post, not in comments.